# if no cookies are set i want to echo cookies are empty

Tags: php, cookies

**check wether cookies are available or not**

```
$d=0;
//**data is stored in cookies as arrays**
if(is_array($_COOKIE['data']) {
    //**data increment by 1 if found**
    $d=$d+1;
}
//**if data not found echo data not found**
if($d==0) {
    echo "data is not present";
}
else{
    echo "data presrnt";
}
```

**I am getting notice undefined variable data**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP: "Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undef)

Comment: change `is_array` to `isset` and you forgot a `)` at the first if.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use isset to check vars set or not:

```
$d=0;
//**data is stored in cookies as arrays**
if(isset($_COOKIE['data']))
    if(is_array($_COOKIE['data']){
    //**data increment by 1 if found**
        $d=$d+1;
    }
//**if data not found echo data not found**
if($d==0){
echo "data is not present";
}
else{
echo "data presrnt";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can check the existance of a variable with `isset()` function like this :

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['data']) && is_array($_COOKIE['data']){
  echo "data present";
} else{
  echo "data is not present";
}
```

you can also check if a variable exist and not empty with `empty()` function like this :

```
if(!empty($_COOKIE['data']) && is_array($_COOKIE['data']){
  echo "data present and it's not empty";
} else{
  echo "data is not present";
}
```

empty values are : `null, "", 0, "0", 0.0, false, [], $var// undeclared var`

also i see that your storing an array in the cookie, i suggest for best practice serializing the array before storing in a cookie like this :

```
setcookie('data', serialize($data), time()+3600);
```

to get it's value all you have to do is :

```
$data = !empty($_COOKIE['data']) ? unserialize($_COOKIE['data']) : null;
```

Comment: thanks for the solution got the answer before but was running wrong file